# Text-based adventure and combat game

Tags: python, beginner, adventure-game, battle-simulation

I'm new to coding and this is a text based adventure game with combat. Sleep and choice functions based on idea from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/52292/179642. Map idea from Codecademy battleship tutorial.

The actions in the `fight` function are not in a loop because attacks reduce the opponent's hp but healing affects your own hp.

Any comments on new ideas/features, better coding methods greatly appreciated.

```
import random, time, sys

#initial variables or settings, and map generation
hp = 100
rMap = [('G', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'W'), ('F', 'F', 'G', 'W', 'M'), ('B', 'W', 'W', 'G', 'M'), ('F', 'F', 'G', 'G', 'G'), ('F', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'V')]
pMap = []
for x in range(5):
    pMap.append(['?'] * 5)
legend = {'X': 'You', '?': 'Unexplored', 'G': 'Grassland', 'V': 'Village', 'F': 'Forest', 'M': 'Mountain', 'B': 'Bridge', 'W': 'Water', 'C': 'Castle'}
enemy = {'G': ('Wolf', 30, 0, 33, 33, 50), 'F': ('Bandit', 30, 1, 50, 33, 50), 'M': ('Troll', 80, 0, 33, 50, 50), 'C': ('Dragon', 170, 2, 0, 0, 100), 'B': ('Ogre', 100, 0.5, 100, 100, 100)}
posR = 4
posC = 4
inv = {'Bow' : 1, 'Arrow' : 0, 'Potion' : 0}
action = {'Punch': (8, 12, 'p'), 'Kick': (6, 20, 'k')}


def wait(value):    #can be commented away for quicker testing
    #time.sleep(value)
    pass


def new_loc():  #whether there is an enemy when the player moves to a new location
    for i in enemy:
        if rMap[posR][posC] == i:
            if random.randint(1, 100) <= enemy[i][5]:
                fight(enemy[i][0], enemy[i][1], enemy[i][2])
                loot(enemy[i][3], enemy[i][4])
                if i == 'C':
                    print ('You win! Congratulations!')
                    sys.exit()
    updatepos()
    turn()


def turn():  #every turn or action by the player
    global hp
    print ('What do you want to do?')
    wait(0.5)
    print ('t to Travel, i to view Inventory, m to view Map')
    c = choice(['t', 'i', 'm'])
    if c == 't':
        print ('Which direction do you want to move?')
        d = []
        if posR != 0:
            if rMap[posR - 1][posC] != 'W':
                print ('f to move forward')
                d.append('f')
        if posR != 4:
            if rMap[posR + 1][posC] != 'W':
                print ('b to move backward')
                d.append('b')
        if posC != 0:
            if rMap[posR][posC - 1] != 'W':
                print ('l to move left')
                d.append('l')
        if posC != 4:
            if rMap[posR][posC + 1] != 'W':
                print ('r to move right')
                d.append('r')
        sel_dir = choice(d)
        if sel_dir == 'f':
            move(-1, 0)
        if sel_dir == 'b':
            move(1, 0)
        if sel_dir == 'l':
            move(0, -1)
        if sel_dir == 'r':
            move(0, 1)
    if c == 'i':
        showInv()
        turn()
    if c == 'm':
        updatepos()
        turn()


def start():    #introduction to the game
    print ('Your village has been burnt down by a dragon!')
    wait(0.5)
    print (' ')
    print ('You have to find it and take revenge!')
    print (' ')
    updatepos()
    turn()


def showAction():   #for debugging player actions in battle
    for i in action:
        print (i, action[i])


def updateAction():   #for updating actions linked to items
    if inv['Potion'] > 0:
        if 'Heal' not in action:
            action['Heal'] = (40, 50, 'h')
    if inv['Potion'] == 0:
        if 'Heal' in action:
            action.pop('Heal')
    if inv['Arrow'] > 0:
        if 'Shoot' not in action:
            action['Shoot'] = (30, 40, 's')
    if inv['Arrow'] == 0:
        if 'Shoot' in action:
            action.pop('Shoot')


def showInv():    #for viewing inventory
    global hp
    for i in inv:
        if inv[i] > 0:
            print (i + ':', inv[i])
    if inv['Potion'] > 0:
        updateAction()
        print('Do you want to drink a Potion? y/n')
        drink = choice(['y', 'n'])
        if drink == 'y':
            h = random.randint(action['Heal'][0], action['Heal'][1])
            hp += h
            print('You used a Potion')
            wait(0.5)
            print('You healed yourself for %d HP!' % h)
            wait(0.5)
            inv['Potion'] -= 1
            print('You have %d Potions left' % (inv['Potion']))
    turn()


def move(r, c):    #when the player moves
    global posR
    global posC
    posR = posR + r
    posC = posC + c
    wait(0.5)
    if r == -1:
        print ('Moving Forward...')
    if r == 1:
        print ('Moving Backward...')
    if c == 1:
        print ('Moving Right...')
    if c == -1:
        print ('Moving Left...')
    new_loc()


def updatepos():    #updating the map position
    pMap[posR][posC] = 'X'
    if posR != 4:
        pMap[posR + 1][posC] = rMap[posR + 1][posC]
    if posR != 0:
        pMap[posR - 1][posC] = rMap[posR - 1][posC]
    if posC != 4:
        pMap[posR][posC + 1] = rMap[posR][posC + 1]
    if posC != 0:
        pMap[posR][posC - 1] = rMap[posR][posC - 1]
    showMap()
    wait(0.5)
    print ('You are now in %s' % legend[rMap[posR][posC]])


def showMap():  #prints the map and legend (for revealed areas)
    print ('Map:')
    for row in pMap:
        for i in row:
            print (i, end = ' ')
        print()
    print (' ')
    legList = []
    for row in pMap:
        for i in row:
            legList.append(i)
    for i in legend:
        if i in legList:
            print (i, legend[i])
    print (' ')


def choice(list):   #get a valid choice from the user
    while True:
        userChoice = input('Choose an action:')
        userChoice = userChoice.lower()
        if userChoice in list:
            return userChoice
        else:
            print ('Invalid choice. Try again.')


def fight(enemy, eHP, level):   #fighting an enemy
    print ('%s appeared!' % enemy)
    wait(0.5)
    global hp
    enemyHP = eHP
    while True:
        if hp <= 0:
            print ("You died :(. Game over")
            sys.exit()
        wait(1)
        print ('Your hp: %d, %s hp: %d' % (hp, enemy, enemyHP))
        wait(1)
        updateAction()
        act = []
        for i in action:
            print (i + ': ' + str(action[i][0]) + ' - ' + str(action[i][1]))
            act.append(action[i][2])
        act_str = ', '.join(str(x) for x in act)
        print ('Choices: ' + act_str)
        pmove = choice(act)
        wait(0.7)
        if pmove == 'p':
            d = random.randint(action['Punch'][0], action['Punch'][1])
            enemyHP -= d
            print ('You punch %s for %d damage!' % (enemy, d))
        elif pmove == 'k':
            d = random.randint(action['Kick'][0], action['Kick'][1])
            enemyHP -= d
            print ('You kick %s for %d damage!' % (enemy, d))
        elif pmove == 'h':
            h = random.randint(action['Heal'][0], action['Heal'][1])
            print ('You used a Potion')
            print ('You heal yourself for %d HP!' % h)
            inv['Potion'] -= 1
            print ('You have %d Potions left' % (inv['Potion']))
            updateAction()
            hp += h
        elif pmove == 's':
            d = random.randint(action['Shoot'][0], action['Shoot'][1])
            print ('You used an Arrow')
            print ('You shoot %s for %d damage!' % (enemy, d))
            inv['Arrow'] -= 1
            print('You have %d Arrows left' % (inv['Arrow']))
            updateAction()
            enemyHP -= d

        if enemyHP <= 0:
            print("You defeated %s!" % enemy)
            return

        wait(1)
        emove = random.randint (1, 3)
        if emove == 1:
            dam = random.randint(1, 5) + 10 * level
            print ('%s scratches you for %d damage!' % (enemy, dam))
            hp -= dam
        elif emove == 2:
            dam = random.randint(6, 10) + 0.5 * level
            print ('%s bites you for %d damage!' % (enemy, dam))
            hp -= dam
        else:
            heal = random.randint(9, 15) + 1 * level
            print ('%s healed for %d HP!' % (enemy, heal))
            enemyHP += heal


def loot(a, p): #probability of getting loot from enemy
    wait(1)
    pArrow = random.randint(1, 100)
    pPotion = random.randint(1, 100)
    if pArrow <= a:
        inv['Arrow'] += 1
        print ('You found an Arrow!')
        wait(0.5)
        print('You now have %d Arrows' % inv['Arrow'])
        wait(0.7)

    if pPotion <= p:
        inv['Potion'] += 1
        print ('You found a Potion!')
        wait(0.5)
        print('You now have %d Potions' % inv['Potion'])
        wait(0.7)


start()
```

Comment: I'm not very good at Python so I don't have any criticism other than to say, I've briefly played your game, got into a fight with a wolf, defeated the wolf and thoroughly enjoyed it. :)

Comment: One thing you might consider is putting another new line after `Choose an action:` to give a little separation between each turn.

Comment: @I0_ol Glad you enjoyed it! I'll implement a turn counter along with the other updates so the user knows which turn they are on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice work!

Here are some things you can improve:

- Style: [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - you can check it with http://pep8online.com/ and there are many editors / editor-plugins that autocorrect or at least complain.
- `#can be commented away for quicker testing` is useless
- Variable names:

  - `inv`: `inventory` would be better
  - What is an `rMap`, what a `pMap`?
- Documentation: Adding [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring) is usually a good idea.

### Object Orientation

You could create a couple of objects and assign attributes / functions to them:

- `Game`: Command line interactions, contains the other objects.

  - Has the map(s) as a property
- `Player`: Has an intentory, a position, hp, ...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!. Forgot to remove the `#` in `wait`. `rMap` is the real map, but is not shown to the player so there is some element of exploration. `pMap` is the map shown to the player, and is updated to reveal the adjacent areas whenever the player moves to a new location. I'll update their names to reflect that. Right, realised that I used an object oriented language but did not use any objects... Silly me! Creating a class would also be a better way to manage the enemies' stats instead of a list within a dictionary.